# Return type error in eXist-db

Tags: exist-db

I have just realized my logger is very active in the case of a function responsible for generating epubs. The problem is it works as expected. Hence I wonder what is going on here.

The error:

```
java:org.exist.xquery.XPathException, exerr:ERROR The actual return type does not match the sequence type declared in the function's signature: epub-util:render-epub(node()+, xs:string) xs:base64Binary. Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 0.
```

… epub is properly served to the client.

As for `exerr:ERROR`, I checked the general log in `$EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB-INF/logs/exist.log`. There are no associated errors caught.

The suspected function:

```
declare function epub-util:render-epub($entries as node()+, $name as xs:string) as xs:base64Binary {
    let $zip-file    := compression:zip($entries, true())
    let $archiveName := $name
    return
        response:stream-binary($zip-file, 'application/epub+zip', lower-case(replace($archiveName, ' ', '-')) || '.epub')
};
```

I run eXist on Ubuntu Server 14.04, eXist-db is 3.0.RC1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response:stream-binary()` is a very special function, that in essence directly writes bytes to a **servlet** output stream , hence it can only be used in the REST interface.

It can only write a byte stream to a HTTP agent, that is e.g. your web browser. It is not possible to store this data in a variable.

I agree that even `item()` is not a good thing, it should be something like `void` but that does not exist.

The common use-case it to have this expression as the last function call in a xquery script. A similar construct we use in the [JFreechart](https://github.com/eXist-db/jfreechart/blob/develop/web/examples/xyareachart-advanced.xq) library.

Comment: Understand. I use it really for exposing the query's result to the browser. It works great but throws the error on the background. I should also note it throws it only in case of streaming of epubs or zip files, pdfs are ok.

Answer (score 2):

According to the eXist-db function documentation for [`response:stream-binary()`](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/response&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.response.ResponseModule#stream-binary.3), this function returns `item()`, not `xs:base64binary`.  Replacing the return type with `item()` should fix the error.

Comment: Well, it is true, thanks. However, it still throws the error, it only reports `item()` instead of `xs:base64Binary`. This needs some patience, apparently. (`... declared in the function's signature: epub-util:render-epub(node()+, xs:string) item(). Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 0.`)

Comment: You're right, I misread the error message. Hmm, I have a feeling - but a question to the list or hipchat would probably be the best route to an answer - that response:stream-binary() operates on the HTTP layer, has side-effects, and is therefore a sort of "magic" function. I'll post a question about this.

Comment: Would it be possible the error is thrown because of something around my function? I mean the function is called by another function, my scenario is a bit broader. And for streaming pdfs, stream-binary() does not throw this error.

Comment: The `stream-binary' function is so generic, that it is yet unlikely that there is an issue in that area. Please could you check your console and your exist-db log for hints? I think there is your answer.....